# electron - how to use ffmpeg within an electron app

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, electron

In the last release (v0.31.0) electron comes with a statically linked FFMpeg library (not the command line tool, see [#2588](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2588))

I am aware of the many nodejs modules for ffmpeg, but they all look like an api to the command line tool, so how can I ideally access the ffmpeg library bundled with electron and encode a stream?

Comment: I once wrote a native C++ wrapper around some basic decoding functionality of FFMPEG for node, I could post it and you could try to adapt it to your needs if you'd like. I think that would be the only way to use FFMPEG directly without the command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible, since there is no decent `ffmpeg` library for node.js. Meaning, there are only such that abstract the CLI. However it is possible to compile and link `ffmpeg` as node native addon, which simply no-one seems to have done yet. So the advice, unfortunately, would be to write this kind of abstraction and include the lib into your electron build

Comment: So, basically, what you're saying is - they bundled ffmpeg with electron, but we can't use it? (not without additional hassle at least)

Answer (score 12):

*Disclaimer: This is a shameless plug for [ffbinaries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffbinaries) Node module and [ffbinaries.com API](http://ffbinaries.com) I created.*

I was looking for the answer to this a while ago and couldn't find anything useful. I decided to put something together myself and thought I'd come back here in case you still need it.

I created [ffbinaries downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffbinaries) to achieve this. I just started this two nights ago so might be still lacking but give it a try.

Still very much work in progress, currently (at 0.0.12) it doesn't set permissions on the file yet but it downloads the required binaries just fine.

**Edit:**
ffbinaries has reached version 1.0.0 milestone a while back - nice, stable and it does set permissions correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to bundle the precompiled static ffmpeg binary with an electron app; of course you'll have to make sure you bundle the correct binary with the correct distro.  I have a complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38373289/3198281).