# How to bundle git with Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gitlab

First of all, I am aware of this question:
[how to bundle git with an electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104523/how-to-bundle-git-with-an-electron-app)

The answer didn't help me though.

I don't want to autoupdate anything, I want to clone git repos through my Electron application.

Is there either a

- Javascript only solution that can clone private Gitlab repositories
- way to bundle the Windows/Linux/Mac git cli tools together with my application to have them do the cloning for me

Any help is much appreciated!