# How can I add MongoDB Server as Windows package dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, electron

I'm trying to build and share an application based on **Node.js** and the **Electron** technology, but I want that precompilled package (.exe or .msi, for example) install the **MongoDB Server** software.

**For Ubuntu** packages I just have to add the MongoDB Server to the list of dependencies of my software (in package.json configs), and then the package manager (APT) will install that for the client.

**For Windows** otherwise I saw that some (in fact, mostly of them) games on Steam install DirectX or other dependencies when the game is being installed, but I can't figure out how to do this or how to configure it in the Electron configs.

*So the question is:* Can I "put" the **MongoDB Server** install program inside the precompilled package of my Windows application?

Comment: If your database is small, you can use lowdb instead of mongo: https://github.com/typicode/lowdb

Comment: Thanks! It can help me. But I was wondering if I can do what I had posted.
Anyhow, thanks again.

Comment: Take a look to this link: https://www.nosqlclient.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for a generic solution allowing to [embbed precompiled binaries with electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152533/bundling-precompiled-binary-into-electron-app).
But the installation logic need be added if you binary isn't a standalone application.

Another methodology is described [here](https://medium.com/@ganeshrvel/bundle-a-precompiled-binary-or-native-file-into-an-electron-app-beacc44322a9) step by step and two reference github projects are provided [here](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/tutorial-electron-bundle-binaries/) (minimal) and [here](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/openmtp) (real project).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is an old problem, but still worth the knowledge.