# Binary executable included in NPM dist installation package

Tags: node.js, svn, npm

Is it possible to include a binary executable in NPM package? I am struggling to do so on macOS.

I am working on an electron application which uses SVN. Using svn-spawn package I am able to communicate with the svn if it's installed on the machine. However, I would like to not to install SVN and my application separately.

Since SVN works as a single executable - either svn.exe on Windows or svn on macOS, I can edit the following block in node_modules/svn-spawn/lib/svn.js

```
var Client = function(options) {
    this.option({
        program: '<path_to_svn>/svn.exe'
    }).option(options);
};
```

After I package it:

- works on Windows (even after uninstalling svn - meaning svn became a part of the application)
- works on macOS when svn is still in the directory
- doesn't work on macOS when svn is deleted

What is the right way of including executables like that in npm installation?

Comment: A lot of the gulp packages are shipped with binaries. You can check out [jpegtran-bin](https://github.com/imagemin/jpegtran-bin) for example. If you look at the profiles of the maintainers you'll find more packages that are also shipped with binaries.

Comment: Is this basically storing binaries on gitHub instead of local file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem - this tread helps:
[bundling precompiled binary into electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152533/bundling-precompiled-binary-into-electron-app)

You can copy over a file by updating package.json

```
  "build": {
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "resources/${os}",
        "to": "Resources/bin",
        "filter": ["**/*"]
      }
    ],
```

Then referencing this file from your script.