# Packaging different binaries per platform for Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron application and I've created a small daemon binary written in Go that is to be packaged along with the application as an `extraResource`. However, there are different versions of this binary that need to be packaged depending on the platform, specifically, `agent.exe` for Windows and `agent` without the extension for MacOS, and for Linux, the same filename as Mac.

I have these binaries in the `bin` directory in my project root:

```
├── bin/
│   ├── windows/
│   │   └── agent.exe
│   ├── mac/
│   │   └── agent
│   ├── linux/
│   │   └── agent
```

Testing for Windows, I included the `bin/windows` directory, and it works fine (packages that exe in the resources directory as expected)

Here is the relevant snipped of my package.json

```
"build": {
  "win": {
    "icon": "build/app.ico",
    "target": [
      {
        "target": "nsis",
        "arch": [
          "x64"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "nsis": {
    "include": "build/installer.nsh",
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
    "license": "build/eula.txt",
    "installerIcon": "build/app.ico",
    "artifactName": "...",
    "shortcutName": "..."
  },
  "extraResources": [
    "bin/windows/agent.exe"
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to do this? As it is now, I would have to edit the package.json file by changing the `extraResources` value in between different platform builds, which for obvious reasons is not ideal (as I could forget and wind up including the wrong binary by forgetting to change it back).

Note that I am not supporting 32-bit Windows, so all Windows builds would include the same (64-bit) binary.

I am using electron-builder 19.50.0

Answer (score 3):

Add three new directories to your `build` directory: `win`, `mac` and `linux`, as is my sample folder structure above (changing `windows` to `win`), and add all the platform-specific binaries (and anything else that needs to be packaged with the distribution) into their respective directories.

Then add the following to your `build` section of `package.json`:

```
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": "bin/${os}",
    "to": "bin",
    "filter": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
]
```

Once packaged, those files will be added to the `bin` directory of your resources root, so the following files and directories appear in your `resources` directory. In my case, for the windows package that is built in `dist/win-unpacked/resources` (relative to project root)

```
app.asar.unpacked/
bin/
app.asar
electron.asar
elevate.exe
```

This way, once your app is installed on the target system, it can be accessed at runtime using `process.resourcesPath`:

```
const binaryFileName = process.platform == 'win32' ? 'binfile.exe' : 'binfile';
const binaryFile = path.join(process.resourcesPath, `bin/${binaryFileName}`);
...
spawn(binaryFile, [...args]);
```

Credit to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152533/bundling-precompiled-binary-into-electron-app/45152204#45152204) here on Stack Overflow.