# Use ffmpeg from an electron app

Tags: ffmpeg, electron

I intend to build a basic video editor desktop app. I have built a working prototype in python ( using kivy ). In this prototype I directly call the command line ffmpeg tool.

How can I incorporate ffmpeg into my electron app?

Answer (score 1):

Last year it sounds like it was not possible or at least very hard to do this [electron - how to use ffmpeg within an electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290967/electron-how-to-use-ffmpeg-within-an-electron-app). But it looks like someone may have made a [Node Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffbinaries) since then (see last answer of that question).